# How would I fit a polynomial to a given set of points, that falls inside a given range? (ideally done manually without computer)

Tags: math, curve-fitting, polynomials

Let's say I've fitted a polynomial to a set of 7 data points using gaussian elimination to bring a matrix to row echelon and then reduced row echelon form. I've done this all by hand, and when graphed, the polynomial goes through each point. Success! BUT, the polynomial goes too far up in between a couple of these points. Ideally, the polynomial doesn't go above the highest data point, or below the lowest data point. I don't care what it does outside of the domain of the data points. Right now it goes far above the highest data point, so it is effectively useless for my case.

Is there any way I can redo these calculations, but in a way that ensures the polynomial falls within a given range (inside the domain of the data points)? After calculating the polynomial, I can restrict domain so that it doesn't extrapolate outside of the given data, but I CAN'T restrict range because it will make the function discontinuous.

Ideally I can do all of this by hand, without a computer, but I'm open to other options.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I guess you must mean a polynomial of degree 6. It's generally considered problematic to fit high-order polynomials to data, for exactly the kind of problem you've encountered. How about a low-order spline, such as a cubic spline. Also take a look at so-called monotone splines, which restrict the value of the interpolated function. By the way, this question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.